# How to compare two different size arraylists and check for order of elements

Tags: java, arraylist

How can i compare two different size arraylists and check the order of elements?

1.First check is ArrayList1 is subset of list2

2.Second check is ArrayList2 has same order as List1, ignoring random elements

```
Arraylist1{"this", "is", "a", "coding", "test"};
Arraylist2{"this", "is", "random1", "a", "random2", "coding", "random3", "test"};
```

The test will pass if List2 is in this order:

```
"this" "is" "a" "coding" "test"
```

The test will fail if List 2 has any other order like:

`"a", "is", "coding", "test", "this"`, or if any of these 5 words are missing.

The program should ignore any number of randoms values (like random1, random2, and random3) in List 2.

How can I achieve this scenario?

I tried `for` loops and iterators. It didn't work, they gave me common elements of both ArrayList but not the "order". What else can I do?

1. `for` loop using:

   ```
   list1.contains(list2.get(i)))
   ```

   But this is comparing only values and doesn't check for order.
2. Iterator with `while` loop:

   ```
   Iterator<String> List1_Iterator = List1.iterator();


   while (List1_Iterator.hasNext()) {
   }
   ```

   This also doesn't check for order of elements.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, when asking questions which contain pieces of code please format it nicely, doing this will result in higher quality question and get you answers way faster.

Comment: I would compare both arrays, then remove everything that is not the same from array2. After that concat both to strings and compare if they are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to first create a copy of list 2 called `list2Copy`, then remove all the elements in `list2Copy` that does not exist in `list1`. Now you just need to compare if they are exactly equal to each other.

```
List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1,3,5);
List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
ArrayList<Integer> list2Copy = new ArrayList<>(list2);
list2Copy.removeIf(x -> !list1.contains(x));
return list1.equals(list2Copy);
```

Here's another approach with a smaller time complexity:

```
if (list1.size() > list2.size()) {
    // definitely not same order
    return false;
}

int list1Index = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i < list2.size() ; i++) {
    if (Objects.equals(list2.get(i), list1.get(list1Index))) {
        list1Index++;
        if (list1Index == list1.size())  {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
// at the end, list1Index should be the same as list1.size() if list2 is in the same order.
return false;
```

Comment: Sorry, `list1 = {1}, list2 = {1,1}`. Result is `false`, but should be **true**. Additionally: you create temporary array (this is not mandatory for this simple task), and `remove` on `ArrayList` slow down performance.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik fixed. And yes I realised the first one is not very fast, that’s why I added the second approach. I create the copy because list2 might not support remove.

Comment: Well, i understand that we compare two arraylists using the .equals().. what does object.equals does? Sorry, i am still learning..  is it a built-in method or are we passing it as parameter like: public boolean equals(Object object) {

Comment: @oleg.cherednik it is built in. I could have also written `list2.get(I).equals(list1.get(list1Index))` but that will through an exception if `list2.get(I)` is null.

Comment: list2.get(I).equals(list1.get(list1Index)) gives me an index out of bounds exception, with index3, size 3.. i m confused why is it checking for index 3. and how to avoid that..

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this simple process as per your steps. 
1) compare the elements.
2) compare the order.

```
import java.util.*;
class Stack1
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("First");
        list.add("name");
        list.add("is");
        list.add("Jay");

        ArrayList<String> list2=new ArrayList<String>();
        list2.add("First");
        list2.add("name");      
        list2.add("is");
        list2.add("Sudeep");

        ArrayList<String> list3=new ArrayList<String>();            

        for(int i=0;i<list2.size();i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<list.size();j++)
            {                       
                if(list2.contains(list.get(j))==true)
                {
                    if(list2.get(i)==list.get(j))
                    {
                        list3.add(list2.get(i));
                    }   
                }
                else{ break; }
            }
        }

        if(list.equals(list3))
        {
            System.out.println("true");
        }
        else{System.out.println("false");}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arraylist is indexed so, you can loop over the smallest list and then check for the mismatch by comparing the value at the indices. A method which does the same- will return true only if the elements are in correct order in both the lists ( one list is a subset of the other and the elements are equal in the same order), in a efficient way.

```
private boolean checkForEqualityInorder(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {
        if (list1.size() < list2.size()) {
            for (int i=0; i <list1.size(); i++){
                if( !list1.get(i).equals(list2.get(i))) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (int i=0; i <list2.size(); i++){
                if( !list2.get(i).equals(list1.get(i))) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The above method accepts two lists, and will return true only if one is subset of the other (checked in order).

Enhancing the same method for your problem:

```
private boolean checkForEqualityInorder(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {
        for (int i=0, k=0; i <list1.size(); i++, k++){
            if (list2.get(k).startsWith("random")) {
                i--;
                continue;
            }
            if(!list1.get(i).equals(list2.get(k))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You start with the first element of the first list and you try to find it in the second list. If/When you find it, you assign the index of the element in list 2 to a local variable (indexList2). Then you go to the second element of the first list and try to find it in list 2 but you don't start at index 0 but at the indexList2. You keep on going until you've looped over all the element in list 1 (and found them in list 20 --> test is successful, otherwise, test is a failure

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final BiPredicate<List<String>, List<String>> isHasSameOrder = (one, two) -> {
    Iterator<String> it1 = one.iterator();
    Iterator<String> it2 = two.iterator();

    nextWord:
    while (it1.hasNext()) {
        String word = it1.next();

        while (it2.hasNext())
            if (word.equals(it2.next()))
                continue nextWord;

        return false;
    }

    return true;
};
```

---

**Demo**

```
List<String> one = Arrays.asList("this", "is", "a", "coding", "test");
List<String> two = Arrays.asList("this", "is", "random1", "a", "random2", "coding", "random3", "test");
System.out.println("same order: " + isHasSameOrder.test(one, two)); // true
```